# How to get the coordinates from Tweepy?

Tags: twitter, geocoding

I have the following code for retrieving tweets. The geocode specified is an area within New York State. However, when I print the location using print(json_reply['user']['location']), it is printing the location as Voorburg, Netherlands.  I guess this is the location specified by user in the profile information. Also, geocode is always returning null. I am interested in Tweets from New York state alongwith the co-ordinates.

```
tweets = api.search(q='xyz', lang='en', since='2016-11-02',until='2016-11-06', geocode='43,-75,90km', count=1)

json_str = json.dumps(tweets[0]._json)
print(json_str)
json_reply = json.loads(json_str)
print(json_reply['text'])
print(json_reply['created_at'])
print(json_reply['user']['location'])
print(json_reply['geo'])
```

Voorburg, Netherlands

Answer (score 2):

You can actually do this with tweepy's search API.

First get the `place_id` via...

```py
>>> places = api.geo_search(lat='43', long='-75', max_results=10)
>>> places[0].id
u'23e921b82040ccd6'
```

Then use tweepy's search API with the `place:<place_id>`.

```py
tweets = api.search(q='place:23e921b82040ccd6', count=100)
```

See: https://dev.twitter.com/rest/public/search-by-place